# How do properly delete this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, action, destroy

Something is seriously not adding  up here.. My page just refreshes, nothing happens, it never touches any of my debuggers hanging out on all my methods except for index.

**my html:**

```
<%- for image in @images %>
  <%= image.attachment_file_name %>

  <%-# link_to_delete image, :url => destroy_image_admin_wysiwyg_path(image.id) %>
  <%= link_to 'delete', { :url => destroy_image_image_path(image.id) },
        #:confirm => 'Are you sure?',
        :post => true
     %>

  <br />
<% end %>
```

**my controller**

```
def destroy_image
  debugger
  @img = Image.find(params[:id])
  @img.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to admin_image_rotator_path }
  end
end
```

**My routes:**

```
map.resources :images, :member => { :destroy_image => :post }
```

**My disgusting hack that works that I will replace as soon as I find something better**

I moved the action over to a simpler controller I built myself.

Changed my routes to :

```
admin.resources :wysiwygs, :member => { :destroy_image => :post }
```

Changed my html :

```
<%= link_to 'delete', :controller => "wysiwygs", :action => "destroy_image" %>
```

But when I clicked on the link..it brought up.. the `show` action ?? fffffffffuuuuuuu

I retaliated by just moving my action to the show action, and passing a hidden field in my html..

```
<%= link_to 'delete', :controller => "wysiwygs", :action => "destroy_image", :hidden_field => {:value =>  image.id} %>

  def show
    # this was previously in destroy_image
    @img = Image.find(params[:hidden_field][:value])
    @img.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_image_rotator_path }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Maybe a `before_filter` is stopping the action from being reached? Also, that's an unusual approach -- using GET to delete is generally considered unwise.

Comment: `:post => true` doesn't look right. Did you try `:method => :post`?

Comment: Yes.. tried it. I'm using spree and yes there is a complicated before_filter load, so I've tried swapping to some of my simpler controllers but it produces the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're going down the wrong path here. If a `before_filter` is blocking your action, *figure out why*. Use `skip_before_filter :filter_name` if the filter is not needed.

Don't use `show` actions or HTTP GET for deletes. Even if it works, it will confuse things down the road. Use a DELETE verb:

`map.resources :images, :member => { :destroy_image => :delete }`

pass it in the link helper:

```
<%= link_to "delete", destroy_image_image_path(image), :method => :delete %>
```

And use `ImagesController#destroy_image` to perform the action. Better yet, consider using the standard RESTful `ImagesController#destroy` which `map.resources` gives you for free.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what was wrong in the first place, but in your second, working solution, i think you should write your `link_to` as follows:

```
link_to 'delete', :controller => "wysiwygs", :action => "destroy_image", :id => image.id
```

That at least would send you to the correct action.
Depending on your routes, you will have to make this a `method => :post` or not.
Check your `rake routes` output, it will show you what are the possible routes, and also what names they got, which in turn you can use as a method (add `_path` or `_url` at the end). Then it should be even easier to write something like:

```
link_to 'delete', wysiwygs_destroy_image_path(image)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a POST but your resource says that :destroy_image is only available via GET. Try changing your route to:

```
map.resources :images, :member => { :destroy_image => :post }
```

Also, take a look at your `link_to`. The second parameter takes a URL, not a hash that has a :url key. As mentioned elsewhere, depending on your Rails version you may need `:method => :post` instead of `:post => true`. In Rails 2.3.8, you would want this line instead:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', destroy_image_image_path(image), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: Yes, great point. But alas, it makes no difference. It still only refreshes.

Comment: Your link_to might be weird too. I updated the answer with more details. If that doesn't work, I'd recommend trying to curl to see if you can manually access that URL. If you can, then your link generation is weird. If not, it's a problem with your before_filter.

Comment: yikes..strange.. i found something that works and posted it above, but it make me throw up in my mouth. so careful reading it.